# Incomplete traversal (using link inversion) of binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I created a program that constructs a binary tree given its preorder and inorder traversals and traverses the binary tree in preorder, inorder, and postorder using link inversion. My program executes but for some reason, the traversals are incomplete. Below is my function for the preorder traversal:

```
void PRE_LINK_INVERT(struct BinaryTreeNode *Root)
{
    struct BinaryTreeNode *father; struct BinaryTreeNode *curr_node; struct BinaryTreeNode *child;
    if(Root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    father = NULL;
    curr_node = Root;
1:  VISIT(curr_node);
    child = curr_node->left_child;
    if(child != NULL)
    {
        curr_node->left_child = father;
        father = curr_node;
        curr_node = child;
        goto 1;
    }
2:  child = curr_node->right_child;
    if(child != NULL)
    {
        curr_node->right_child = father;
        curr_node->tag = 1;
        father = curr_node;
        curr_node = child;
        goto 2;
    }
3:  if(father == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(father->tag == 0)
    {
        child = father->left_child;
        father->left_child = curr_node;
        curr_node = father;
        father = child;
        goto 2;
    }
    else
    {
        child = father->right_child;
        father->right_child = curr_node;
        father->tag = 0;
        curr_node = father;
        father = child;
        goto 3;
    }
}
```

`father` represents the predecessor of the current node, `curr_node` is, well, the current node, and `child` represents either the left or right child of the current node. This function accepts a pointer `Root` which points to the root node of the binary tree. The structure `BinaryTreeNode` is declared:

```
struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    char data;
    int tag;
    struct BinaryTreeNode * left_child;
    struct BinaryTreeNode * right_child;
};
```

Now, the problem when I use the function to traverse a binary tree that has `char preorder[] = "ABCDE";` for its preorder traversal and `char inorder[] = "CBADE";`, for its preorder traversal, what comes out is merely `ABC` and nothing else. I'm positive that the problem does not lie with the function that constructs the binary tree since I used the same function in another program that does the recursive implementation of the binary tree traversals and encountered no problem. Which part of this code should I tinker with?

Comment: Using labels and `goto` is okay in some situations, a very few limited number of situations. Using them instead of loops is *not* one of the okay uses.

Comment: You are modifying the tree while traversing it: `curr_node->left_child = father;` you'll be losing some subtrees.